# Monitoring PHP process on CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, process

I want to monitor a php process activity because sometime it keeps hanging there for a day although I have set time limit but it seems like its not working. I setup a cron job which runs this PHP application.

I tried to attach process from WHM but its not showing me any relevant info except following string

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {146528, 951364448}) = 0
```

Any clue how to monitor process activity?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `strace` - there's a lot of good documentation and even [Youtube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF-p--AH37E&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=PL1683B77BD1209E64) surrounding troubleshooting this behavior.